# Clearing query cache in Symfony2 / Doctrine

Tags: caching, symfony, doctrine

I've recently written my first Symfony2 app and all is well, except now I want to add in some query caching to improve performance and cut down on unneeded queries. I've added the following lines to one particular query's builder:

```php
$query->useResultCache(true)
      ->useQueryCache(true);
```

After the first request, the cache is then used as expected. I can verify that in the profiler. All is great!

The problem is I also have a simple admin panel I wrote that allows the user to modify the content, but after changes the cached version is still being used.

Is there a way I can 'programmatically' tell Symfony2 / Doctrine to clear the query cache as I update the data, or is there a way of configuring this?

It seems like it would be a common issue but I can't find anything on Google relating to the issue!

Comment: could u please let me know how exactly u r able to check the cache is working using the profiler, specifically USING THE PROFILER. I tried checking the amount of database queries and since I´m getting the same amount of queries every time, before and after the cache is supposedly carried out, so I don´t know if it´s working or if it´s supposed to do that, anyway, hints??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I recommend using result cache id - that way you can clear one particular result cache:

```php
$query->setResultCacheId('my_custom_id');
// or shorter notation with lifetime option
$query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'my_custom_id');

// to delete cache
$cacheDriver = $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getResultCacheImpl();
$cacheDriver->delete('my_custom_id');
// to delete all cache entries
$cacheDriver->deleteAll();
```

For more info on cache deleting see:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#deleting